# One Div affecting another

Tags: html, css, web

I have tried +, console sign, < and >. They dont work, could anyone do this code for me? I have been messing around with it for a hour now and I cant seem to get a solution for it.

Sorry for earlier post.

HTML

```
          <ul>  
            <li id="meist">  
                <p><a href="meist.html">Meist</a></p>  
            </li> 
            <li id="seadmed">  
                <p><a href="seadmed.html">Seadmed</a></p>  
            </li> 
           <li id="tooted">  
                <p><a href="tooted.html">Tooted</a></p>  
            <li id="hooldus">  
                <p><a href="tooted.html">Tooted</a></p> 
         <li id="kontakt">  
                <p><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></p> 
        </ul>

<ul>
    <li id="submeist"> <p> ASD </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
     #meist {  
        display: inline;
        float:left;
        width:180px;  
        height:50px;  
        color:#191919;  
        text-align:center;  
        overflow:hidden; 
        background:#990000;
        -moz-border-radius-top-left: 50px;
        border-top-left-radius: 50px;

    } 

    #submeist {
        display:block;
        color:#ccc;
    }

    #meist:hover < li #submeist{
    color: #000
}

   #meist:hover
    {  
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: white;
        font-size: 17.5px; 
        line-height: 15px;
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem here... can you please elaborate your expected output

Comment: When you hover over "meist" you should change the ".submeist" style, But it wont change no matter what.

Comment: So far I can see that you're missing closing `</li>` tags for `<li id="tooted">`, `<li id="hooldus">`, `<li id="kontakt">`.

Comment: Yea.. thanks for pointing that out, I missed them.

Comment: This cannot be done (with your current markup) with pure CSS as the `:hover` element and the element you want to apply color to are not in a relationship expressible by [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nearest solution.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="meist">  
            <li>  
                <p><a href="meist.html">Meist</a></p>  
            </li> 
            <li id="seadmed">  
                <p><a href="seadmed.html">Seadmed</a></p>  
            </li> 
           <li id="tooted">  
                <p><a href="tooted.html">Tooted</a></p>  
            <li id="hooldus">  
                <p><a href="tooted.html">Tooted</a></p> 
         <li id="kontakt">  
                <p><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></p> 
        </ul>

<ul id="submeist">
    <li class="submeist-sub"> <p> ASD </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#meist {  
        display: inline;
        float:left;
        width:180px;  
        height:50px;  
        color:#191919;  
        text-align:center;  
        overflow:hidden; 
        background:#990000;
        -moz-border-radius-top-left: 50px;
        border-top-left-radius: 50px;

    } 

    #submeist {
        display:block;
        color:#ccc;
    }

    #meist:hover + #submeist > .submeist-sub{
    color: #000
}

   #meist:hover
    {  
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: white;
        font-size: 17.5px; 
        line-height: 15px;
    }
```

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/jTBx5/

Comment: Thank you very much.. Didnt know that I could only change class.

Comment: it's not about class.. it's about "+" sign... means adjacent element.. Glad i could help you!! you r welcome.. :)

Comment: But you've changed the markup to make it work. The `.submeist-sub` element will be changed if the previous `<ul>` is hovered now, not just the first `<li>` of the previous `<ul>`

Comment: That is just changing the question to fit _your_ answer. The real answer to this is that it cannot be done in pure CSS _without_ changing the markup!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HZqyA/5/)**

And I don't understand this code

```
#meist:hover < li #submeist{
color: #000
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for

// I found it online And i tought it migh work

#meist:hover < li #submeist{ 
color: #000
}

Comment: @VonHornmeister Actually I have never seen using < symbol in css

Comment: That's not even a valid selector

Comment: And @downvoter so some interest even for giving the reason for downvote

Comment: Any solutions how to solve it ? tried your demo, without any "signs", still didnt work.

Comment: @Sowmya, Author of this question accepted my answer as correct!

Answer (score 1):

As CSS currently has no parent selectors available, what you would like to achieve is not possible with just CSS. You either have to change the structure of your html, or use Javascript to get the desired result. Something like this can be done very easy with jQuery.